# how to resolve org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException exception in thingsboard?

Tags: alarm, thingsboard

on thingsboard i am getting the following error with alarms,can anyone help me with this

> Blockorg.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:531)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy210.findLatestByOriginatorAndType(Unknown Source)
> at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.alarm.JpaAlarmDao.lambda$findLatestByOriginatorAndType$0(JpaAlarmDao.java:87)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
> at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2297)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657)
> at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652)
> at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
> at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
> at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636)
> at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604)
> at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy308.getResultList(Unknown Source)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
> ... 17 more
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column alarmentit0_.propagate_to_owner does not exist
> Position: 460
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
> ... 50 more
> quote